# Oauth 2 "redirect_uri_mismatch: { "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch" }" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I am using oauth2 gem for google login auth. My code looks like

**omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
require "omniauth-google-oauth2"
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'secret-client-id', 'secret-number', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

my **routes.rb**

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

my **view**

```
 <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2", id: "sign_in" %>
```

I am getting this URL after this pages
[image]

[image]

**Where am i going wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding token to the omniauth initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, "id", "secret", {
    client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}},
    scope: 'email profile',
    access_type: 'online',
    setup: (lambda do |env|
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options['token_params'] = {:redirect_uri => 'http://.../auth/google_oauth2/callback'}
    end)
}
end
```